# Template dependent typedefs

Tags: c++, templates, c++11

I am modifying a templated A* search and now have the following class (part of):

```
template <typename TNode, typename THeuristic>
class AStar
{
public:
    //  Typedefs.
    typedef d_ary_heap<TNode*, boost::heap::compare<NodeCompare<TNode>>, boost::heap::arity<4>, boost::heap::mutable_<true>> PriorityQueueType;

    //...
}
```

Until now, I hadn't thought of templatizing the heuristic parameter, so the `Node` class was defined as follows:

```
template <typename T = float>
class Node
{
public:
    //  Typedefs:
    typedef typename AStar<Node>::PriorityQueueType::handle_type HeapHandle;

    //...
}
```

But now since `AStar` takes a second template paremeter for the heuristic the typedef gives a compile error here: `typedef typename AStar<Node ??>...`. Is it possible to make this work somehow while maintaining freedom to specify the heuristic in the `AStar` class?

Comment: I may be misreading your question, but wouldn't giving `THeuristic` a default (which you already know how to do -- you're using it in `Node`) suffice?

Comment: But then would it work if I use a different heuristic than the default one? `HeapHandle` would be of a different type than the correct one, no?

Comment: The `PriorityQueueType` typedef doesn't depend on the `THeuristic` template parameter, so it gives the same type for all possible `THeuristic`s.

Comment: You are right, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could factor your code differently and keep the heuristic-independent part separate:

```
namespace  detail
{
    template <typename T>
    struct AStarHeap
    {
        using QueueType = /* ... */;
        using HandleType = QueueType::handle_type;
        // ...
    };
}

template <typename Node, typename Heur>
struct AStar : detail::AStarHeap<Node>
{
    // ...
};

template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    using HeapHandle = typename detail::AStarHeap<T>::HandleType;
    // ...
};
```

Comment: +1, I found that actually my comment on the question leads to something very similar to your answer (but have posted it separately regardless)

Comment: This is what I did, more or less. Note that `handle_type` is a dependent name so in my case I had to modify that line to `using HandleType = typename QueueType::handle_type`.

Answer (score 2):

Reworking a bit from my comment on the question, here's how I would probably do it:

```
template <typename TNode, typename THeuristic = void>
class AStar;

template <typename TNode>
class AStar<TNode>
{
  // put everything that does not depend on THeuristic here
};

template <typename TNode, typename THeuristic>
class AStar : public AStar<TNode>
{
  // put everything that does depend on THeuristic here
};
```

Looking at it now, this takes much the same approach as Kerrek SB's answer, but has the advantage that your existing code, which uses `AStar<TNode>`, continues to compile so long as it does not attempt to do anything that requires `THeuristic`.

Comment: Thanks. I made use of your suggestions as well: the default trick worked like you said, but I preferred the separation of responsibility into two different classes.